# accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath is not being called

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I have my app perfectly working on the simulator and on the iPhone OS 2.2.1 device.
But I as well have a device with iPhone OS 3.0 installed. And when I tap on a disclosure button, the accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath method is not being called, however color of a disclosure button becomes darker.

Has anyone faced such an issue?

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Now that OS 3.0 is officially out the door:

The problem is with UITableViewCell's accessoryType property.  Use the tableView:accessoryTypeForRowWithIndexPath: delegate method instead, as long as you're targeting both OS 2.x and OS 3.x.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, "accessoryTypeForRowWithIndexPath" has been deprecated.

The clue to the different behavior (between UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator and UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton) is that the disclosure INDICATOR doesn't 'track' whereas the disclosure BUTTON does 'track'.

What you'd have to do is provide your own recognition of where the User tapped in the cell and use that as part of additional code to then call into your

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView*) tableView accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*) indexPath
```

routine - which is what happens with the disclosure BUTTON.

You might want to use something like a UITapGestureRecognizer attached to an AccessoryView in your custom cell.  This thing is normally NIL, so you would need to add a UIView into the cell via IB or programmatically - resize it - and connect it to your cell object.  Then you would add some code to your custom cell's `- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle) style reuseIdentifier:(NSString*) reuseIdentifier` function.

The general idea is shown below.

```
 UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] 
    initWithTarget:myAccessoryView action:@selector(didTap:)];
    tapGesture.delegate = (id <UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>)myTableViewControllerDelegate;
    [containerView addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];
    [tapGesture release];
```

The 'didTap:' function would then forward your code or just do what you might have done in the other routine.

It's sad the three different accessory items are treated differently.  So, if you don't want a giant blue-thing in your cell, it looks like you'll have to come up with some additional code to make things work as you would wish.

One advantage to using an AccessoryView in your custom cell is that you can put a UIImageView in the view and then deposit an image in the UIImageView - which means you can use any image versus the simple disclosure ">".